# Desktop-File to run Python Script with Parameters

Tags: 20.04, python, .desktop

I Tryed to make a `.desktop` file to run a python-script wich has parameters (rpatools)

I tryed to make a bash file a tryed to execute it in many ways but none of them works how ever if i execute the excact same line of code in the terminal (changing the `%u` to the actual file path)

I looked in the internet for similar problems but found nothing

My Trys

`Exec=python '/home/Carslo45/Dokumente/RenPy/EXTRA/RenPy-Decompile/rpatool.py' -x %u`

`Exec=python '/home/Carslo45/Dokumente/RenPy/EXTRA/RenPy-Decompile/rpatool.py' -x %U`

`Exec=sh -e "python '/home/Carslo45/Dokumente/RenPy/EXTRA/RenPy-Decompile/rpatool.py' -x %u"`

`Exec=sh -e "python '/home/Carslo45/Dokumente/RenPy/EXTRA/RenPy-Decompile/rpatool.py' -x %U"`

Also Executing a Bach script (where the %u variable worked)

```
#!/bin/bash
SCRIPT=$(readlink -f "$1")
python '/home/Carslo45/Dokumente/RenPy/EXTRA/RenPy-Decompile/rpatool.py' -x $1 -o /home/Carslo45/.extract
```

And much more
*Edit:
Problem behoben

Comment: By the way, don't execute your Python scripts using `python /path/to/script.py`. Add `#!/usr/bin/python` in the first line of the script, make it executable and execute it just using `/path/to/script.py`. It is much more natural.

Answer (score 0):

make a shell script that does what you wont .
then
run this command (this imports a binary handling library )
`eval "$(curl -L -s https://raw.githubusercontent.com/lnee94/resh/main/l/bintools)"`
After that is done do
`readb path/to/shell/script`

now copy this and put into a file

```
#!/bin/bash

[Desktop Entry]
Jkldfslgas="$(cd $(dirname $0) ;eval "$(xxd -r -p <<< "hex_that_was_printed_from_readb" )")"
Comment=
Exec=sh -c '"$(dirname "$*")"/ok/insert_name.desktop || ([ ! -x "$(dirname "$*")"/ok/insert_name.desktop ] && "$(dirname "$*")"/insert_name.desktop)' dummy %k
GenericName=
Icon=
Name=
Type=Application
```

change `insert_name to the` name
and `hex_that_was_printed_from_readb` to all the text that was printed when you ran readb

Comment: > make a shell script that does what you wont . then run this command (this imports a binary handling library )
How does this Help because the shell script is working but the Python execute isn't.

Comment: this makes a wrapper for a shell script